# integer is required(got type str)

Tags: python, string, date

this program counts the amount of days between two dates

this is the error:

```
line 14, in <module>
    f_date = date(d1, m1, y1)
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

```
#program that counts the amount of days between two dates
from datetime import date

print("Hi,this program counts the amount of days between two dates, press enter and follow the instructions without writing spaces")

d1=int(input("tell me the day of the starting date"))
m1=int(input("now the month"))
y1=int(input("and the year"))

d2=int(input("now i would need the day of the the second date"))
m2=int(input("then the month"))
y2=int(input("and finally the year"))

f_date = date(d1, m1, y1)
l_date = date(d2, m2, y2)
delta = l_date - f_date
print(delta.days)
```

Comment: What did you enter?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't include the inputs you provided that caused the error so that it could be reproduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the datetime.date() function is date(y, m ,d) instead of date(d, m ,y) https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects

This change in code should fix it (assuming your user inputs are correct):

```
f_date = date(y1, m1, d1)
l_date = date(y2, m2, d2)
```